# How to analyze Android APK for compatibility?

Tags: android, apk

Our developer's built an Android APK that cannot be installed on one particular Samsung tablet. It blocks an installation saying "it's not compatible with your tablet" without any more details. Is there any way to get these details and understand, what exactly makes this APK incompatible with the tablet?

Comment: I'd guess it's about the Android OS version. You can check it in the app gradle `minSdkVersion`

Comment: @RafaelTavares It can also be about available hardware, like sensors and so on, and maybe other restrictions in the manifest.

Comment: Sorry did't mentioned this in the question - the same APK worked fine on the same tablet some time ago. So we're sure it's not about Android version but some features or modules. We can't figure out what exactly the tablet sees as incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio go to Build -> Analyze APK...

From there, open up AndroidManifest.xml

There, search for tags like `uses-sdk` (minSdkVersion) and `uses-feature`. There are many more that can cause the incompatibility issue, but these two are the most common ones.

Comment: OK, but then how to understand which feature causes incompatibility?

Comment: minSdkVersion is not an issue (it's 21 which means Android 5.0, while it's 7.1.2 on the tablet)

Comment: Might be anything, really. telephony, fingerprint, nfc